# Wxpython installation failed

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm trying to get wxpython to work with python3.7.0 (32)
I installed it using "pip install wxpython", so I assume that there no compatibility problems.
this is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Scratch\Test.py", line 9, in <module>
    import wx
  File "C:\Python37\wx\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "C:\Python37\wx\core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx._core'
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Seems you have wx in Python37 folder. This is not normal. pip uses to install on Python37/Lib/site-packages