# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx._core' when importing wx in Python 3.11 even though the file exists in the directory

Tags: python-3.x, module, package, wxpython, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to import wx, and getting an error.
I'm using wxPython version 4.2.0, installed with pip 22.3.1.
I'm on Windows 10.

Here's how I get the error and what it says:

```
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\lynns\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wx\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "C:\Users\lynns\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx._core'
```

The file this is seemingly asking for (_core) is in that directory (site_packages\wx\_core).

I've tried reinstalling the package through pip, as well as installing it from a source file provided on wxpython.org (that one fails to even build).
**Update: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything python related on my pc, and the problem still persists.**

I tried looking this problem up and I can't find anything relevant, and the only two topics that come up here on stackoverflow are not helpful to me.
([Wxpython installation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303136/wxpython-installation-failed)) - my package is in the right folder.
([Installation of wxPython on Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879561/installation-of-wxpython-on-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04)) - using a different python version and OS, and hasn't been answered.

What's the cause of this error, and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no official wxPython wheels for Python 3.11 on Windows. But take a look here, you will find unofficial wheels of wxPython for Win10(x64/x86) and Pyhon 3.11:

https://dev.azure.com/oleksis/wxPython/_build/results?buildId=89&view=artifacts&pathAsName=false&type=publishedArtifacts

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error as the OP when I installed wxpython with pip

I was successful using miniconda on Windows 11. I created a conda env with python=3.11 and then used conda to install wxpython.

See:
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall wxPython may solve this issue.
If you have installed wxPython it's better to uninstall wxWidgets module first before you install wxPython.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).